# Can I extract customer name from a serial number?

Tags: php, numbers, unique, generator

I am trying to generate some sort of serial number using a customer name.
This is for a PHP software I am developing. But I have never done trial systems and serial generation and stuff like this.

This is the code I use to generate the serial numbers:

```
<?php
// URL is = http://teionsoft.com/classified/keygen.php?token=
    $token = @$_POST['token'];

    if(empty($token)) 
    { 
        echo '
        <p>Token can not be blank or zero.</p>
        <p>
            <form action="keygen.php" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="token" id="token" placeholder="Type in your full name" /><br /><br />
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get serial!" />
            </form>
        </p>';
        exit;
    }

function serialKey() { 
    // Create a token

    // GUID is 128-bit hex
    $hash = strtoupper(md5($token));

    // Create formatted GUID
    $guid = '';

    // GUID format is XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX for readability    
    $guid .= substr($hash,  0,  5) . 
         '-' .
         substr($hash,  8,  5) .
         '-' .
         substr($hash, 12,  5) .
         '-' .
         substr($hash, 16,  5) .
         '-' .
         substr($hash, 20, 5);

    // temporary code to test base64 codeing / decoding ;

    $string  = $guid;
    $encoded = base64_encode($string);
    $decoded = base64_decode($encoded);
    echo $encoded ."<br /><br />";
    echo $decoded;
}

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    serialKey();
}
?>
```

How can I extract the customer name from the serial number?

Comment: use sha256 instead of md5

Comment: for unique id read this http://php.net/manual/es/function.uniqid.php

Comment: You're mentioning GUID there, but you're not generating a GUID. Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier#Algorithm

Answer (score 2):

If i understand your question correctly, you need to generate a serial number based on the customer name, and later be able to decode the serial number to get the customer name.

You could convert the name to hex, but the string would in most cases get longer than the XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX format you're using now.

Wouldn't it be better to just save the serial number in the database so you just have to check if the serial number is in the same row as the customer name?

Comment: +1 to this answer. It would be better to generate a random serial code, save this into a database alongside customer information and then it can be looked up easily.

Comment: It would, it's just that in some cases that software might not be connected to the internet. So decoding the serial number would verify the serial was generated on my website, after purchase.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you have `$hash = strtoupper(md5($token))` should be a clue that this is an irreversible transform.  You'll need to store the original if you want to use the hash as a lookup key.